# call a imported component in function with React js

Tags: reactjs, import, switch-statement, components

I imported Login component and trying to use in switch case as per the condition, I'm not getting expected result

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Login from './login';

function classListR() {
  render();
}

const handleCloseUserMenu = (event) => {
  const targeted = event.currentTarget.innerText;

  let components;

  switch (targeted) {
    case 'Logout':
      components = classListR();
      break;
    case 'Dashboard':
      components = event.currentTarget.innerText;
      break;
    case 'Profile':
      components = event.currentTarget.innerText;
      break;
    case 'Account':
      components = event.currentTarget.innerText;
      break;
    default:
      components = 'Target Not Found';
  }
  setAnchorElUser(null);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you simply need this

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Login from './login';

function classListR() {
  render();
}

const handleCloseUserMenu = (event) => {
  const targeted = event.currentTarget.innerText;

  let components;

  switch (targeted) {
    case 'Logout':
      components = classListR();
      break;
    case 'Dashboard':
      components = event.currentTarget.innerText;
      break;
    case 'Profile':
      components = event.currentTarget.innerText;
      break;
    case 'Account':
      components = event.currentTarget.innerText;
      break;
    case 'Login':
      components = (<Login />);
      break;
    default:
      components = 'Target Not Found';
  }
  setAnchorElUser(null);
};
```